# If D3 is blank, leave blank (TRUE Blank), else =RAND()

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need all cells in column (J) to be true blanks (doesn't show with COUNTA or VLOOKUP) until data is entered in column (D) in the same row. When the data (combination of letters and numbers) is put in D3 I need J3 to use =RAND(). I have made an example sheet to illustrate the issue and make edits. Thank you to anyone who can help.

[Link ToExample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nh55rrRwYVX2RCC8qQD9c4S-5jq03u2FJCaqi_nlWv0/edit#gid=0)

I have tried looking through several forums, asked everyone I know who has technical knowledge and watched several different YouTube videos. I know ways of using If Else to do other tasks similar to this, but I am struggling to get it to work with the random number.

Comment: Is this about programming within Google Sheets, or is this just about Sheets? Because the latter is off topic if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: [Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) is not off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheets behaves differently than Excel and allows you to set `null` in cells if you don't specify anything in the `if-statement`.

Try this formula and drag down

`=if(ISBLANK(D3),,rand())`

I placed it in your sheet and confirmed it verified as empty with some `counta` and `isblank` formulas.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate you taking the time to help me.